# Is it possible to open all ftp:// URLs in MS Edge (in IE mode)?

Tags: browser, ftp, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

**Short summary**: how to make MS Edge automatically open all links starting with `ftp://` in Internet Explorer mode? Is it possible at all? (Could be also a command line switch, if one exists - I can just create a batch file that runs Edge with the needed parameter).

(By default, `ftp://` links don't open in MS Edge - as in most other browsers - at all, if you didn't define a handler for them. They do open in IE mode, but only if you add the **exact** link to list of "Internet Explorer sites" in Edge - exact, means if you add `ftp://some.server.address/` to the list, then that exact link will work, but `ftp://some.server.address/directory/` won't - so it's just impossible to add all links for even one server)

**Longer explanation**:

As you probably know, Microsoft is starting to remove Internet Explorer from Windows. But there's a problem. IE is currently the only browser that supports the `ftp://` type URLs. Both Chromium-based browsers (Chrome, Chromium, Edge etc.) and Firefox stopped supporting them long ago.

I still often use `ftp://` type links, so I set IE to be my `ftp://` handler and it works perfectly :). But if IE will be removed, I would need another application. However, no FTP client that I have tested seamlessly supports all `ftp://` links. Some of them support only links to directories, but not to files; some don't allow you to change default download location when downloading the file; some require the username to be present in the link for non-anonymous downloads (like `ftp://username@server.address/...`) which of course isn't present in the links that I have. Browser seems to behave best - URLs were designed for browsers, anyway...

So a possible option would be to use MS Edge with its Internet Explorer mode. But here comes the problem described above. I would have to add **all possible links** to Edge's "Internet Explorer sites" list. There seems to be no way to tell Edge "open all `ftp://` links in IE mode". Can it be done?

Comment: Depending on your version, you may have an option like `edge://flags/#enable-ftp`, but it's been recently removed in chromium

Comment: I assume you have attempted to use the *Use the Enterprise Mode IE website list* group policy?

Comment: @Ramhound No, I have used the list built into MS Edge, in Settings. I didn't think there is a difference - thanks for the tip! The instructions to use the Enterprise Mode on MS website are quite unclear - it took some time until I found out that the key point is to download an additional policy file from the website. Using Enterprise mode, it is enough to put only top-level URL into the list, that is good news. However, I still have to add individual servers to the list, there is no possibility to configure a "catch-all" for ftp:// protocol. I will have to live with that.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a browser that is not Chromium-based, so doesn't follow the
drive to abolish the `ftp` protocol.

One such browser is [palemoon](https://www.palemoon.org/), which you can
define as the handler for the `ftp://` protocol (I can help with
establishing the handler).

Comment: I'd rather prefer to stick to what I already have on the computer than to install another browser (a fourth one; I use Firefox for most of my web browsing, Chrome installation is forced by my employer - it is a work computer - because there are some internal web apps that require Chrome, and Edge is provided by Windows). But I will give it a try if there will be no other option.